# Saving changed attributes after onDestroy

Tags: java, android, android-theme

In general, I implemented a style change in my application, but after `onDestroy()` the application style is requested, and I don’t know how to save it.

How to save the selected application theme after closing the application.

The theme is changed as follows, by clicking in the `themes.xml` file, certain attributes are applied.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.BackStackAndroidX" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lt_color_main</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/color_empty</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/color_empty</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/color_empty</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/color_empty</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/color_empty</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <item name="ColorStatusBar">@color/lt_color_appbar</item>
        <item name="ColorAppBar">@color/lt_color_appbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.BackStackAndroidX.LIGHT" parent="Theme.BackStackAndroidX">
        <item name="ColorStatusBar">@color/lt_color_appbar</item>
        <item name="ColorAppBar">@color/lt_color_appbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.BackStackAndroidX.DARK" parent="Theme.BackStackAndroidX">
        <item name="ColorStatusBar">@color/dt_color_appbar</item>
        <item name="ColorAppBar">@color/dt_color_appbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.BackStackAndroidX.MULTICOLOR" parent="Theme.BackStackAndroidX">
        <item name="ColorStatusBar">@color/mt_color_appbar</item>
        <item name="ColorAppBar">@color/mt_color_appbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

When pressed, the following occurs

```
    public static int getThemeId(int theme) {
        int themeId = 0;
        switch (theme) {
            case 0: {
                themeId = R.style.Theme_BackStackAndroidX_LIGHT;
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                themeId = R.style.Theme_BackStackAndroidX_DARK;
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                themeId = R.style.Theme_BackStackAndroidX_MULTICOLOR;
                break;
            }
        }
        return themeId;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try with sharedPreferences?
Store the selected value and inside onCreate() check the stored theme value

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for shared preferences. Here is the official Android site for you: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences